# Cakephp Form Helper Zero-based Options

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having this in my form, the dropdown menu generated is zero-based. i.e. it comes up with `<option value="0">1</option>` and I want make it `<option value="1">1</option>`

```
echo $this->Form->input('numBook', array(
'options' => range(1, 100),
'empty' => __('- Select One -'),
'label' => __('numBook')
));
```

Comment: `print_r(range(1, 100))` aught to make it obvious why the keys are off-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `options` array key used as value, and value used as label, then, your `options` might be looks like this:

```
'options' => array_combine(range(1, 100), range(1, 100)),
```